# Unusual output using map() and filter() in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, filter

I'm trying to learn how to use the map() and filter() functions in Python but when I try and use them in visual studio, I'm getting an unusual output for each one. I know the code is probably wrong, but I can't see what it's outputting which is making it hard to sort out!

Thanks in advance

filter()

```
import functools

f = ["List", "of", "super", "crazily", "long", "words"]

new = lambda a, b: a if (len(a) > b) else b

print (filter(new, f))
```

Serves: filter object at 0x029AD5F0

map()

```
import functools

f = ["List", "of", "super", "crazily", "long", "words"]

map_loop = map((lambda x: len(x)), f)

print (type(map_loop), map_loop)
```

Serves: class 'map', map object at 0x0243D5D0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638898/how-to-use-filter-map-and-reduce-in-python-3-3-0

Comment: Note that `filter` expects a `function` that takes *a single argument*; it's `functools.reduce` that requires a `function` with two arguments.

Comment: Thanks for this. Sorry it looks like I've been working from an old list of exercises online if these functions are pretty much obsolete now. Apologies for the dupe.

Answer (score -1):

you need to use `list` like this:

```
print (type(map_loop), list(map_loop))
```

demo:

```
>>> f = ["List", "of", "super", "crazily", "long", "words"]
>>> print(list(map(len,f)))     # no need of lembda,  `len` is enough
[4, 2, 5, 7, 4, 5]
```

Comment: plz specify reason??