# how to delete empty dict inside list of dictionary?

Tags: python

How can I remove empty dict from list of dict as,

```
{
 "ages":[{"age":25,"job":"teacher"},
         {},{},
         {"age":35,"job":"clerk"}
        ]
}
```

I am beginner to python. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a list comprehension within a dict comprehension ,  `{k:[i for i in v if i] for k,v in d.items()}`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this

```
In [50]: mydict = {
   ....:  "ages":[{"age":25,"job":"teacher"},
   ....:          {},{},
   ....:          {"age":35,"job":"clerk"}
   ....:         ]
   ....: }

In [51]: mydict = {"ages":[i for i in mydict["ages"] if i]}

In [52]: mydict
Out[52]: {'ages': [{'age': 25, 'job': 'teacher'}, {'age': 35, 'job': 'clerk'}]}
```

**OR** simply use `filter`

```
>>>mylist = [{'age': 25, 'job': 'teacher'}, {}, {}, {'age': 35, 'job': 'clerk'}]
>>>filter(None, mylist)
[{'age': 25, 'job': 'teacher'}, {'age': 35, 'job': 'clerk'}]
```

So in your dict, apply it as

```
{
 "ages":filter(None, [{"age":25,"job":"teacher"},
         {},{},
         {"age":35,"job":"clerk"}
        ])
}
```

Comment: This will no longer work in Python3, use generator-expressions instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13638931/570722

Comment: For Python3 use `list(filter(None, mylist))`

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Python 3, simply do:

`list(filter(None, your_list_name))`

This removes all empty dicts from your list.

Answer (score 5):

There's a even simpler and more intuitive way than [*filter*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter), and it works in Python 2 and Python 3:

You can do a ["truth value testing"](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) on a dict to test if it's empty or not:

```py
>>> foo = {}
>>> if foo:
...   print(foo)
...
>>>
>>> bar = {'key':'value'}
>>> if bar:
...    print(bar)
...
{'key':'value'}
```

Therefore you can iterate over *mylist* and test for empty dicts with an if-statement:

```py
>>> mylist = [{'age': 25, 'job': 'teacher'}, {}, {}, {'age': 35, 'job': 'clerk'}]
>>> [i for i in mylist if i]
[{'age': 25, 'job': 'teacher'}, {'age': 35, 'job': 'clerk'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

This `while` loop will keep looping while there's a `{}` in the list and remove each one until there's none left.

```
while {} in dictList:
    dictList.remove({})
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following function:

```py
def trimmer(data):
    if type(data) is dict:
        new_data = {}
        for key in data:
            if data[key]:
                new_data[key] = trimmer(data[key])
        return new_data
    elif type(data) is list:
        new_data = []
        for index in range(len(data)):
            if data[index]:
                new_data.append(trimmer(data[index]))
        return new_data
    else:
        return data
```

This will trim

```
{
 "ages":[{"age":25,"job":"teacher"},
         {},{},
         {"age":35,"job":"clerk"}
        ]
}
```

and even

```
{'ages': [
    {'age': 25, 'job': 'teacher', 'empty_four': []},
    [], {},
    {'age': 35, 'job': 'clerk', 'empty_five': []}],
    'empty_one': [], 'empty_two': '',
    'empty_three': {}
}
```

to this:
`{'ages': [{'age': 25, 'job': 'teacher'}, {'age': 35, 'job': 'clerk'}]}`

Comment: This solved my issue perfectly, either your dictionary is a list of dictionary or dictionary of dictionary. Considering, it should be accepted as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### You can also try this

```
mylist = [{'age': 25, 'job': 'teacher'}, {}, {}, {'age': 35, 'job': 'clerk'}]

mylist=[i for i in mylist if i]

print(mylist)
```

Output:

```
[{'age': 25, 'job': 'teacher'}, {'age': 35, 'job': 'clerk'}]
```