# filter not returning the constructed or matched list

Tags: python

I am learning about `lambda` and `filter` at the moment, so I wonder if someone could please help me understand what I am doing wrong in the following **2** snippets that the result is only printed out as `<filter object at 0x105762668>` instead of what I expect to see:

```
my_list = range(16)

print( filter(lambda x: x % 3 == 0, my_list) )

# Expected to see [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15]



mylist = ["dog", "cat", "wildcat", "thundercat", "cow", "hooo"]

r = re.compile(".*cat")

newlist = filter(r.match, mylist)

print(newlist)

# Expected to see ["cat", "wildcat", "thundercat"]
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638898/how-to-use-filter-map-and-reduce-in-python-3

Comment: Put briefly, **filter** is an iterator, like **range**. If you want all of its results at once then you should wrap it with **list**, like so: `print( list( filter(lambda x: x % 3 == 0, my_list) ) )`.

Comment: @vaultah Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Bill Bell This is exactly what I needed. I was missing the `list()` wrapper. Many thanks.