# Why doesn't filter method return a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
In [17]: mult3 = filter(lambda x: x % 3 == 0, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [18]: mult3
Out[18]: <filter at 0x7f97fab8be48>
```

Why doesn't mults show the actual list result after the filter?

Comment: `mult3 = list(mult3)`

Comment: [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) returns an iterator in python 3

Comment: Because in Python 3, filter returns a filter object which is an iterator: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter. Also, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638898/how-to-use-filter-map-and-reduce-in-python-3

Comment: @mgilson your dupe is much better ... I undid mine, care to finish the job?

Comment: But how come me I get  it when i run the script in my console? [3,6,9]

Comment: @TariiqHenryBbosa because you're using Python 2.x ...

Comment: Yah thanks @ZeroPiraeus thats right am using python 2.7.I guess i also learnt that about python 3