# Replacing the zeros with the previous value in "list of lists" in python

Tags: python

I have a list called "Names.

```
Names = [['Bassett', 'Richard', '1745-04-02', 'M', 'sen', 'DE', 'Anti-Administration', 1745], ['Bland', 'Theodorick', '1742-03-21', 'M', 'rep', 'VA', '', 1742], ['Burke', 'Aedanus', '1743-06-16', 'M', 'rep', 'SC', '', 0]]
```

In the names list if the year column (index 7) equals 0 then I want to replace it with the previous year value. For eg: the third list's year value is 0, I want to replace it with 1742.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the latest valid year and pass it on to the next stage. `reduce` passes a value from one stage to the next and since lists are passed by reference we can modify the lists in place.

```
Names = [['Bassett', 'Richard', '1745-04-02', 'M', 'sen', 'DE', 'Anti-Administration', 1745],
         ['Bland', 'Theodorick', '1742-03-21', 'M', 'rep', 'VA', '', 1742],
         ['Burke', 'Aedanus', '1743-06-16', 'M', 'rep', 'SC', '', 0]]

def fill_year(year, ns):
    if ns[7] == 0:
        ns[7] = year
    return ns[7]


reduce(fill_year, Names, 0)
print Names
```

Apparently `reduce` is deprecated in python3.

Try:

```
year = 0
for ns in Names:
    ns[7] = year if ns[7] == 0 else ns[7]
    year = ns[7]
```

Comment: @MJP looking at the [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638898/how-to-use-filter-map-and-reduce-in-python-3), no. _Removed reduce(). Use functools.reduce() if you really need it; however, 99 percent of the time an explicit for loop is more readable._

Comment: Hi Mike, the second code is much more readable. I will go with it.

Comment: The second code is actually more what I was aiming for when I took on the question.  It is probably even more readable to code it like the `fill_year` with the explicit `if` statement rather than the conditional expression.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But, the reduce function doesn't work in Python 3. That's the reason why I didn't use it.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, I meant rather than `ns[7] = year if ns[7] == 0 else ns[7]` code the assignment as `if ns[7] == 0: ns[7] = year`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
Names = [['Bassett', 'Richard', '1745-04-02', 'M', 'sen', 'DE', 'Anti-Administration', 1745],
     ['Bland', 'Theodorick', '1742-03-21', 'M', 'rep', 'VA', '', 1742],
     ['Burke', 'Aedanus', '1743-06-16', 'M', 'rep', 'SC', '', 0]]

for ele in range(len(Names)):
    if Names[ele][7] == 0:
        Names[ele][7] = (Names[ele-1][2].split('-'))[0]

print(Names)
```

Explanation:

Using `for-loop` and `range(len())` itearte over the `length` number of times

```
for ele in range(len(Names)): #it will iterate over three times as len -> 3
```

Next check for the `year` value at index `7` if it equals to `0` then copy the previous year means the year present in previous iteration step means `ele-1`. For example if it is in ele(2nd iteration) then it will fetch the year from `ele-1` (1st iteration).

```
  Names[ele][7] = (Names[ele-1][2].split('-'))[0]
```

The year is combined in `date` format. To retrieve only the year use the `split()` to split the string using `-` as delimiter

```
 '1742-03-21' -> [1742, 03, 21]
```

So the year is in index `0`.

```
 (Names[ele-1][2].split('-'))[0] -> we get year from here
```

Finally update the year of current `ele` to the one which we got.

Output:

```
[['Bassett', 'Richard', '1745-04-02', 'M', 'sen', 'DE', 'Anti-Administration', 1745], ['Bland', 'Theodorick', '1742-03-21', 'M', 'rep', 'VA', '', 1742], ['Burke', 'Aedanus', '1743-06-16', 'M', 'rep', 'SC', '', '1742']]
```

Comment: @MJP: Is this what you are expecting ?

Comment: The code works perfectly. But I am unable to understand this part:        Names[ele][7] = (Names[ele-1][2].split('-'))[0]

Comment: @MJP: Let me know if you got clarified. or need more information ?

Comment: I think you don't have to split the date here. You just need to use the "year" value in index 7.  I understood the code!!

Comment: @MJP: But if the consecutive elements have `0` at index 7 like this `[['Bassett', 'Richard', '1745-04-02', 'M', 'sen', 'DE', 'Anti-Administration', 1745], ['Bland', 'Theodorick', '1742-03-21', 'M', 'rep', 'VA', '', 0], ['Burke', 'Aedanus', '1743-06-16', 'M', 'rep', 'SC', '', 0]]`  ? That's why I used split to get the year from previous element

Comment: @MJP: If you think you got desired answer please confirm the answer by voting

Answer (score 0):

The [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) package has a function for this and is useful for many other types of operations on tabular data.

If you are willing to use it you could solve this fill problem as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(Names, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'Year'])
df['Year'] = df['Year'].replace({0: None}).fillna(method='ffill')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
         A           B           C  D    E   F                    G  Year
0  Bassett     Richard  1745-04-02  M  sen  DE  Anti-Administration  1745
1    Bland  Theodorick  1742-03-21  M  rep  VA                       1742
2    Burke     Aedanus  1743-06-16  M  rep  SC                       1742
```

UPDATE:

As pointed out by @miradulo, [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html?highlight=replace#pandas.Series.replace) has a method argument so you can do the operation in one go as follows:

```
df['Year'] = df['Year'].replace(0, method='ffill')
```

Comment: A much better way to do this with Pandas is using the `to_replace` parameter of `replace`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use unpacking:

```
Names = [['Bassett', 'Richard', '1745-04-02', 'M', 'sen', 'DE', 'Anti-Administration', 1745], ['Bland', 'Theodorick', '1742-03-21', 'M', 'rep', 'VA', '', 1742], ['Burke', 'Aedanus', '1743-06-16', 'M', 'rep', 'SC', '', 0]]
new_names = [b+[Names[i-1][-1]] if not a else [*b, a] for i, [*b, a] in enumerate(Names)]
```

Output:

```
[['Bassett', 'Richard', '1745-04-02', 'M', 'sen', 'DE', 'Anti-Administration', 1745], ['Bland', 'Theodorick', '1742-03-21', 'M', 'rep', 'VA', '', 1742], ['Burke', 'Aedanus', '1743-06-16', 'M', 'rep', 'SC', '', 1742]]
```