# how to incorporate 'if' condition into for loop statement

Tags: python, python-3.6

```
data = [(1,'hi'),(2,'hello'),(3,'hi'),(4,'hi'),(5,'hello'),(6,'hello'), 
(7,'hi'),(8,'hello')]
new_data = []
for i in data:
    if i[1] == 'hi':
        new_data.append(i)
print(new_data)
```

output:[(1, 'hi'), (3, 'hi'), (4, 'hi'), (7, 'hi')]

i am a beginner in python.
i want the same output but want to reduce the amount of code in the'For' loop and be more efficient.

Comment: Your code is easy to understand, and does exactly what it should do. The few extra lines shouldn't matter too much.

Comment: `new_data = [x for x in data if x[1]=='hi']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your loop is fine, you can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
new_data = [i for i in data if i[1] == 'hi']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension and a filter to write in on one line. There is a good explanation on filters available at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638898/how-to-use-filter-map-and-reduce-in-python-3). Using filters you can make use of [lazy evaluation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/163985/why-is-the-concept-of-lazy-evaluation-useful/164002), which benefits the execution time.

```
data = [(1,'hi'),(2,'hello'),(3,'hi'),(4,'hi'),(5,'hello'),(6,'hello'), (7,'hi'),(8,'hello')]
new_data = list(filter(lambda i: i[1] == 'hi', data))
```

**Output**

```
[(1, 'hi'), (3, 'hi'), (4, 'hi'), (7, 'hi')]
```