# How to remove empty string in a list within a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7

I have a data file. It is a csv file. I have created a dictionary like this from it: {movie_id: ('title', ['genres']}. I want to know how to remove the empty strings that come about in the list of genres within the tuple within the dictionary

The data file(.csv) is like this:

movie_id title                   genres
68735    Warcraft                Action Adventure Comedy
124057   Kids at the round table

```
def read_movies(movie_file: TextIO) -> MovieDict:

    """Return a dictionary containing movie id to (movie name, movie genres)
    in the movie_file.
    """

    line = movie_file.readline()
    while line == '':
        line = movie_file.readline()

    reader = csv.reader(movie_file)

    movie_dict = {int(rows[0]): (rows[1], rows[4:]) for rows in reader}

    return movie_dict
```

I expect the output when movies_dict is called to be:

```
{68735: ('Warcraft', ['Action', 'Adventure', 'Fantasy']), 293660: ('Deadpool', ['Action', 'Adventure', 'Comedy']), 302156: ('Criminal', ['Action']), 124057: ('Kids of the Round Table', [])}
```

What I get with my code:

```
{68735: ('Warcraft', ['Action', 'Adventure', 'Fantasy']), 293660: ('Deadpool', ['Action', 'Adventure', 'Comedy']), 302156: ('Criminal', ['Action', '', '']), 124057: ('Kids of the Round Table', ['', '', ''])}
```

Comment: can you provide us with an example of your file ?

Comment: What are you trying to do with your while-loop???

Comment: The while loop is just to skip over the header of the csv file @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @DjaballahDJEDID how do I put the data of the file here in correct format can I post a picture?

Comment: yes try adding a picture to the original post

Comment: @DjaballahDJEDID I cannot add a picture but I added what the file looks like look at it like this headers = movie_id : genres, then data for each movie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dictionary = {}
dictionary['a']= ('name',['','p','q','',''])
for key in dictionary.keys():
    x,y = dictionary[key]
    print(x,y)
    dictionary[key] =(x, [s for s in y if len(s)!=0])
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear how your file looks like, how big and why do you want to parse it this way and not using Pandas (for example).

But answering your question.
You can achieve this in your code this way

by replacing this line

```
movie_dict = {int(rows[0]): (rows[1], rows[4:]) for rows in reader}
```

by

```
movie_dict = {int(rows[0]): (rows[1], [e for e in rows[4:] if e != '']) for rows in reader}
```

Comment: According to the "expected output" example, it doesn't seem to me the OP wants his genres list unpacked - it remains a separate list

Comment: By doing this what happens is that the list of genres in my tuples just becomes another string in the tuple and I don't want that also

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to go would be to filter the empty strings out:

```
non_empty = lambda s: len(s) > 0
movie_dict = {int(rows[0]): (rows[1], list(filter(non_empty, rows[4:]))) for rows in reader}
```

`non_empty` is an anonymous function determining a string (or really anything which we can call `len` for) isn't empty. It returns `True` for non-empty strings and `False` for empty ones.
By passing it to `filter` among `rows[4:]` we get a copy of `rows[4:]` with only the values which returned `True`, hence the non-empty ones.

You could as well use list comprehension to filter out the empty strings: `[s for s in rows[4:] if len(s) > 0]` will do the exact same thing.

Both ways, the second item in your tuple is a list filtered for non-empty strings.

Comment: yeah that actually makes a lot of sense and helps. Thank you so much @Neo

Comment: actually it isnt working as in my genres list within the tuple I am recieinv this in my output: <filter object at 0x105188b00>

Comment: Apparently (which actually makes sense), `filter` returns a "filter object", which doesn't actually do the filtering but remembers it and does it "lazily", meaning only when it's needed. You can use `list(filter(...))` to get that... But you could really use the list comprehension solution which now seems more compact

Comment: I changed the answer anyway to accommodate that

Comment: You can read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638898/how-to-use-filter-map-and-reduce-in-python-3 for further investigation

Comment: I didn't have to use list comprehension solution as using list(filter(...)) made everything work out. Thanks again!