# Why doing list(filterObject) cleasn up the filterObject after the first time

Tags: python-3.x

I'm learning on lists (python 3.6), ie

Having following list object:

```
sourceList=[3,5,2,5,2,61,2]
```

Then filtering

```
mylist=filter(lambda x: x==2,sourceList) #this creates a filter object in mylist
```

Then if I run

```
>>> mylist
<filter object at 0x0000018DE7B98438>
>>> list(mylist)
[2, 2, 2]
>>> list(mylist)
[]
>>> mylist
<filter object at 0x0000018DE7B98438>
```

I will get the list the first time, but If I try again now I get an empty list.

What's going on here or what I'm missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use filter, map, and reduce in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638898/how-to-use-filter-map-and-reduce-in-python-3)

Comment: `filter` returns a `generator` in python3. Generators are iterators and are exhaustable. This means that once `list` iterates over all the values in the generator, the generator runs out of values. Subsequent calls of list happen on an empty generator.

Comment: Thanks @Primusa makes all sense.