# How do I compare value at x in array to value at x +1?

Tags: python

I've noticed that in a lot of coding problems there is a need to compare x to x+1 in an array, although I've never found a good way to do it.

How can I do it? Is it even possible? Sorry if this seems like a noob question, I am not very good yet.

Here is what I usually try:

```
       for x in range(len(nums)):
                    if nums[x] > nums[x+1 < len(nums)]:
                        count +=1
```

Comment: `for x in range(len(nums) - 1):`

Comment: Array?  what arrays?  Python has lists, not arrays.  You have to a package like `numpy` to get arrays.  Indexing of lists is quite restrictive (esp. compared to `numpy`).  A boolean index (from the `<`) is just translated to `0/1`, so is rarely useful.

Answer (score 1):

No problem! we all start somewhere :)
Here's one way to do it:

```
for x in range(len(nums) - 1):
   if nums[x] > nums[x+1]:
       #do something
```

Answer (score 1):

len(nums) will return the *number* of values in an array, and when you are looping through an array, the first value in that array will be accessed using an index of 0, not 1.

for example:

```
nums = [1,3,5,7]
len(nums) == 4
```

if you run

```
for x in range(len(nums)):
   if nums[x] > nums[x+1]:
       #code here
```

you will get an error at nums[x+1] because on the last iteration, it becomes nums[3+1] which is nums[4], and that index is not in that array. Your last index is 3.

So what you really want is

```
for x in range(len(nums)-1):
   if nums[x] > nums[x+1]:
       #code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reduce`

For example, to get the max of a list, you could do the following

```
import functools 
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(functools.reduce(lambda a,b : a if a > b else b, arr))
```

Output

```
5
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638898/how-to-use-filter-map-and-reduce-in-python-3) is great to refer to as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through the adjacent pairs of any sequence with this helper function:

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> [[s0,s1], [s1,s2], [s2, s3], ...]"
    a, b = iter(iterable), iter(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)


nums = 1, 5, 3, 7
count = 0
for x, x1 in pairwise(nums):
    if x > x1:
        count += 1
```