# Explain the meaning of the .filter code in python

Tags: python, pyspark

I am new to Bigdata and Python. Kindly explain the meaning of

```
.filter("year*10000+month*100+day between {0} and {1}".format(start,end))
```

Comment: Did you forget a `"`? They don't match (there is only one)

Comment: Yes, but can you explain the meaning of .filter("year*10000+month*100+day between {0} and {1}".format(start,end))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use filter, map, and reduce in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638898/how-to-use-filter-map-and-reduce-in-python-3)

Answer (score 2):

The author of the following code

```
.filter("year*10000+month*100+day between {0} and {1}".format(start, end))
```

tries to filter the rows from data frame that are between `start` and `end` date.

Obviously the author does not have a column "date", so they make a date out of `year`, `month`, and `day` columns, e. g. if *year = 2020*, *month=10*, and *day=15*, the product is date *20201015*. Maybe, it would be helpful, when there are parenthesis in the equation:

```
.filter("(year * 10000) + (month * 100) + day between {0} and {1}".format(start, end))
```

However, this code is wrong, because you cannot make the date like this for months from January to September, so I would recommend to rewrite it.