# Data from txt input to list - Python

Tags: python, list

I have data in text file :

```
2,58 1,23 0,14
6,58 4,2  1,3
```

I want to have this data from my text file in list written in this format:

```
[[2, 58, 1, 23, 0, 14]
 [6, 58, 4, 2, 1, 3]]
```

I tried this :

```
folder = open('text.txt', encoding = 'utf-8')
data = [numbers.strip().replace(',',' ').split(' ') for numbers in folder]
folder.close
print(data)
```

But I received result like this : `[['2', '58', '1', '23', '0', '14']['6', '58', '4', '2', '1', '3']]`

If I'm trying to set `int()` to numbers in many places in list I receiving this error : *int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not `list`*

So I need just change all string in this list from `str` to `int`, can you help me, please?

Comment: `list(map(int, numbers.strip().replace(',',' ').split(' ')))`

Comment: `folder.close()`

Comment: if you don't mind pandas, `pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=',|  | ', header=None)`

Comment: @Chris_Rands [just vote to close as a dupe!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/843953)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/642154/843953

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [`map()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638898/how-to-use-filter-map-and-reduce-in-python-3?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C87.2793) function it takes two arguments where one is function, condition, etc and the second is an iterable objects like list, set, etc so in your question will be like `map (int ,yourlist)` and after cast it into list like `list(map (int ,yourlist))` for more see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303347/getting-a-map-to-return-a-list-in-python-3-x) to know why you should cast it

### Example

```
folder = open('text.txt', encoding = 'utf-8')
data = [list(map(int, numbers.strip().replace(',',' ').split(' '))) for numbers in folder]
folder.close()
print(data)
```