# "list object is not callable" when trying to filter a list

Tags: python

When I try to run the code below, I am hit with an error:

```py
nums=[1, 2, 3, 11, 22, 33]
even = list(filter(lambda a : a %2==0 , nums))
print(even)

double = list(map(lambda a : a*a , even))
print(double)

sum = reduce(lambda a,b: a+b, double)
print(sum)
```

The error message is:

> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: need more information. Plus need to show code related to `reduce`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use filter, map, and reduce in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638898/how-to-use-filter-map-and-reduce-in-python-3)

Comment: Please give us the full traceback. The error is not only that one line you show in your question.

Comment: You might have used `list` or `filter` as the name of one of your variables in the code you don't show us. You do the same with `sum` where you overwrite the builtin [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum). That's a bad idea. Don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR -- Looks like you're facing datatype issues while running Python 2.x code on Python 3.x environment.

---

Detailed explanation as given on [How to use filter, map, and reduce in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638898/how-to-use-filter-map-and-reduce-in-python-3/13638960#13638960) is as below:-

You can read about the changes in [What's New In Python 3.0](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html). You should read it thoroughly when you move from 2.x to 3.x since a lot has been changed.

The whole answer here are quotes from the documentation.

**[Views And Iterators Instead Of Lists](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists)**

> Some well-known APIs no longer return lists:
>
> - [...]
> - [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#map) and [`filter()`](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#filter) return iterators. If you really need a list, a quick fix is e.g. `list(map(...))`, but a better fix is often to use a list comprehension (especially when the original code uses lambda), or rewriting the code so it doesn’t need a list at all. Particularly tricky is `map()` invoked for the side effects of the function; the correct transformation is to use a regular `for` loop (since creating a list would just be wasteful).
> - [...]

**[Builtins](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins)**

> - [...]
> - Removed `reduce()`. Use [`functools.reduce()`](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) if you really need it; however, 99 percent of the time an explicit `for` loop is more readable.
> - [...]