# Pythonic way of multiplying contents of list by one another in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I note this question has already been asked here, but this mostly deals with python2:
[How can I multiply all items in a list together with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840379/python-multiply-all-items-in-a-list-together)

With the demise of reduce in python3 (see [What is the problem with reduce()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181543/what-is-the-problem-with-reduce)), what is the best way to multiply numbers in an iterable together?

eg. `[1,3,7,1,2]` -> `1*3*7*1*2`

I'm using something like this at the moment

```
def foo(list)
    sum = 1
    for i in list:
        sum *= i
    return sum
```

I'd really like a one liner, without having to `from functools import reduce`

Something like: `total = sum(b for a,b in items)`
but for multiplication

Comment: Why the objection to `from functools import reduce`?

Comment: Also, what's wrong with a `for` loop? It's explicit, it's simple, it's Pythonic.

Comment: Using `functools.reduce(operator.mul, lst)` is pythonic in my book. So is importing that one module.

Comment: @chepner - nothing in particular really. I assume moving it out of the namespace was to discourage use.

Comment: It was moved out of builtins because it didn't justify being a builtin, that doesn't mean it's not the right tool for this job.

Comment: @shipt: no, it was not seen as generally useful enough to be kept in the default namespace. Just like the `array` type is not in the default namespace. It is still *useful for specific tasks*. Otherwise it'd have been removed outright.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I see, thanks for clarifying. Guess I misunderstood _why_ it had been moved out of builtins

Comment: @JoelCornett - again, nothing. Just felt a bit more verbose. Particularly having to initialise the sum variable which for something this trivial I'd argue isn't all that pythonic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The major objection to `reduce` seems to be abusing it with arbitrary reduction functions. If you stick with simple, pre-existing associative operators, there's no reason not to use `reduce`.

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

x = reduce(mul, [1,3,7,1,2])
```

You can even go one step further and compose `reduce` and `mul` using `functools.partial`.

```
product = functools.partial(functools.reduce, operator.mul)

x = product(b for a, b in items)
```

Comment: Note that in python3, the `reduce()` function has been removed from the global namespace, so you would need to import it by `from functools import reduce`

Comment: @rhlobo Which I have in the first example. I left out the implied `import functools, operator` from the example for `product`.

Comment: Sorry, I must be getting crazy