# How can I subtract all items in a list with Python?

Tags: python

What I want to do is subtract all the items in that list by order:

```
>>> ListOfNumbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9 - 10  # should be computed
-53
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the [`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) function:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x - y, lst)
-53
```

Or using [`operator.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.sub) instead of the `lambda`:

```
>>> import operator
>>> reduce(operator.sub, lst)
-53
```

Note that in Python 2.x [`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) is a built-in, so you don't need to import it.

Comment: Any reason to prefer the lambda over `operator.sub`?

Comment: None - you can use `operator.sub`, if you wish. I guess, it can even be slightly more efficient.

Comment: Please consider also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181543/what-is-the-problem-with-reduce

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through the array and subtract:

```
result = ListOfNumbers[0]
for n in ListOfNumbers[1:]:
    result -= n
```

Or, as [vaultah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2301450/vaultah) pointed out:

```
result = ListOfNumbers[0] - sum(ListOfNumbers[1:])
```

Comment: That would give a wrong result, though.

Comment: @vaultah, fixed.

Comment: Okay, why not `ListOfNumbers[0] - sum(ListOfNumbers[1:])` then?

Answer (score 2):

With `itertools.accumulate` and `operator.sub` functions:

```
import itertools, operator

l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
print(list(itertools.accumulate(l, operator.sub))[-1])   # -53
```

---

This not pretends to be better than posted `functools.reduce()` solution, but gives an additional feature - intermediate subtraction results for each pair (the 1st item stays as starting point):

```
[1, -1, -4, -8, -13, -19, -26, -34, -43, -53]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way of doing it, assuming items as input list.

```
if len(items) == 0:
    print(0)
elif len(items) == 1:
    print(items[0])
else:
    print(items[0] - sum(items[1:]))
```

Comment: might want to properly format this?

Comment: formatted the code @aws_apprentice