# Sum a List with Different Operator in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, sum

In python we can sum a list as: `sum(list_of_integers)`.

Now sum is just an operation among two elements with the operator `+`.

What if I want to sum a list with different operator like `or`, `and`, `xor` etc?

I could do it manually one by one using a `for` loop, but there must be a better way.

Comment: what do you mean by **sum a list with or and xor** ?

Comment: how about using "-"?

Comment: I think he means if you have a list [x1, x2, x3] then he wants to do `x1 or x2 or x3` without using a manual loop over all elements

Comment: Use `functools.reduce`, but some operations have other builtins. Example, `all` -> `and` and `any` -> `or`.

Comment: An example for XOR: `from functools import reduce reduce(lambda x,y:x^y, l)`. Is this what you want?

Comment: @bro-grammer reduce is not built in in python NameError: name 'reduce' is not defined

Comment: @mourinho It definitely is, i tested python2.6, 2.7 and 3 and they all work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`functools.reduce` is perfect for this use-case. It takes a function to apply to the accumulated value and the next value, the iterable you want to reduce, and optionally an initialiser.

For example, bitwise-or-ing every value in a list:

```
import functools

functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a ^ b, [1, 2, 3])
```

This is equivalent to `1 ^ 2 ^ 3`.

Comment: but reduce is not built-in in python anyway without importing any library..thanks

Comment: Not using the standard library seems like an extremely arbitrary restriction. Is this for homework?

Comment: @mourinho `reduce` *used* to be part of the `builtins` module in Python 2, but it was relegated to `functools` because, well, [Guido just doesn't like it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181543/what-is-the-problem-with-reduce). Not wanting to use core libraries seems like an artificial restriction. Otherwise, note, Guido recommends a for-loop. And that seems like the most straightforward way if you don't want `reduce`

Comment: @mourinho Then you should've mentioned that in the question. There's no reason not to use the standard library

Answer (score 5):

The alternative to `functools.reduce` is to write an explicit `for` loop:

```
def xor_reduce(args):
    result = 0
    for x in args:
        result ^= x
    return result

xor_reduce([1, 2, 3])
```

If you are going for the `reduce` way (not so unreasonable for this, IMO), I would make use of the `operator` module:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import xor

reduce(xor, [1, 2, 3])
```

The `operator` module (which is in the standard library and should therefore always be available) also defines all other standard operations as functions, but for `or` and `and` a trailing `_` is added because they are reserved keywords:

```
from operator import or_, and_
reduce(or_, [1, 2, 3])
reduce(and_, [1, 2, 3])
```

Although for these two you could use the built-in functions `any` and `all`:

```
any([1, 2, 3])
all([1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: This is much better than the accepted answer, showing a manual and the `reduce` way to do it. Absolutely no need for a `lambda`. Faster and more elegant