# How does lambda function work with reduce function in python?

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, reduce

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
print(reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [1,2,3,4,5]))
```

O/P -> 15

What is `x` and `y`? Which is the accumulator here? Does the accumulator always has to be the first argument (i.e. `x` here)
What happens when no initialization is done? What is the default value picked?

Comment: did you import `reduce` from `functools`?

Answer (score 1):

An extended form of this code which would might be easier to understand

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

x = 0  # Default value
for i in lst:
    y = i
    x = x + y
print(x)
```

Or, if you consider the lambda function:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
x = 0

def func(x,y):
    x = x + y
    return x

for i in lst:
    x = func(x, i)

print(x)
```

As you can see, `x` is the accumulator here. You won't be able to use the `reduce` method if you don't specify the accumulator as the first argument.

Hope that clears how your code works.

Update: As @Wolf points out, we can specify an initial value for the args for reduce method. Updated `x` to be 0, as that is the default value.

Comment: The list that OP used is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. But my assumption regarding the initial value was incorrect as pointed out by your answer.

Comment: However, you are probably right in the idea to switch to a loop. This seems the advice given indirectly by moving the `reduce` function from built-in functions to `functools`, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/181543/2932052 for more

Answer (score 1):

I think the documentation of *[functools.reduce(function, iterable[, initializer])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)* is quite readable. The iteration is carried out, applying the operation from left to right to consecutive elements and accumulating the result in the left operand. To be sure about the aspects in question, it helps to create variations of above code.

In the following example, we get the sum of the elements; we see that there is no implicit `1` as "default" value at work:

```
>>> print(reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [2,3]))
5
```

The reduction stops if there are no elements left in the iterable:

```
>>> print(reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [1]))
1
```

The reduction ***fails*** if there are no elements at all:

```
>>> print(reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, []))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    print(reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, []))
TypeError: reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value
```

The optional `initializer` value is used to start the reduction (and immediately stops it if there are no elements):

```
>>> print(reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [], 0))
0
```

So `x` is indeed the accumulator that is initialized with the optional `initializer` value before entering the iterable. And `y` is the next value from the iterable, if there are no elements (left), the `function` is ignored.

Here another example to better understand the roles of `x` and `y`:

```
>>> print(reduce(lambda x, y: x - y, [1,2,3], 10))
4
```

In single-step mode, above reduction would look like this:

```
x = 10   # initializer
y = 1    # from iterable
x = x-y  # x==9
y = 2    # from iterable
x = x-y  # x==7
y = 3    # from iterable
x = x-y  # x==4
4        # result
```